# How can I set a checkbox to unchecked when I click cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a bootbox script that displays a custom alert.  When clicking cancel I need the checkbox that fires the alert to go back to unchecked.

This is my checkbox when checked

```
<div class="checkbox">
     <label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="enroll-deposit" checked="" data-original-title="" title="" value="True"> I am not enrolling in Direct Deposit
     </label>
</div>
```

and this is my bootbox script thats fired on click

```
$(document).on("click", "#enroll-deposit", function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "True") {
        var url = "@Url.Action("waivetask", "OBProcess" , new { id=ViewBag.DocId, tid=ViewBag.TaskId })";
        var desc = "Direct Deposit";
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "Are you sure you want to waive " + "<strong>" + desc + "</strong>",
            title: "Waive Direct Deposit",
            buttons: {
                main: {
                    label: "Cancel",
                    className: "btn-default",
                    callback: function() {
                        //NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: "Waive and Move On to Next Task",
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function() {
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am not sure what to do when the user clicks the cancel button.  I want to uncheck the enroll-deposit box.

Comment: set `checkbox.checked = false` where `checkbox` is your DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to uncheck:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
```

And instead of using:

```
var val = $(this).val();
```

You could use:

```
var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
```

Maybe its best to refactor your code like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#enroll-deposit", function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');    
    if (isChecked) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("waivetask", "OBProcess" , new { id=ViewBag.DocId, tid=ViewBag.TaskId })';
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "Are you sure you want to waive <strong> Direct Deposit </strong>",
            title: "Waive Direct Deposit",
            buttons: {
                main: {
                    label: "Cancel",
                    className: "btn-default",
                    callback: function() {
                        //NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: "Waive and Move On to Next Task",
                    className: "btn-danger",
                    callback: function() {
                        window.location.href = url;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
$("#enroll-deposit").prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked is not an attribute. It's actually a property. Looks like you're using jQuery so in your "else" statement you could do

```
$(this).prop("checked",false);
```